# Asynchonous Loading of Javascript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am trying to load all the Facebook/Twitter/Google paraphernalia on my pages asynchronously, in order to stop them slowing down the page loading. I thought I had the right code to do it, but it seems to be not working.

All the bits of code are held together in a php include like this:

```
    <!-- Facebook -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<!-- Google +1 -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.___gcfg = {lang: 'en-GB'};
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>

<!-- Twitter -->
<script>
!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");
</script>

<!-- Analytics -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();
</script>
```

When I test a page on webpagetest.org the page load time is about 5 seconds and I can see that there is a shed load of requests to facebook et al occurring before the page is completed. When I delete the scripts the page load comes down to a more respectable 1.9 seconds.

Is it me?

Comment: Your question is, "is it me?". I don't know what you mean, so I'm just going to guess yes with a 50% chance of being right.

Answer (score 1):

You can do one thing:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
      ....
      ....
      <script src='http://....'/>
      <script src=''/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Which will load the script immedeately after it loads the page's important contents.
You can prioritise your contents and scripts to be loaded this way.

Comment: And yes if you want to write javascript inside the script tag you can write the script inside the tag and ignore the 'url' attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try using the javascript **defer** attribute:

```
<script defer="defer"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

for modern browsers you can also use

`<script type="text/javascript" async src="..."></script>`